# Python/Selenium - Can not download file in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I'm facing an issue downloading this file:

https://www.vidahomeloans.co.uk/intermediaries/documents

- Residential
- Product Guide & Rate Sheets
- Residential Rate Sheet -> Then press download next to it

If I downloading WITHOUT headless mode, then all works great, but in the headless mode, I receive `example.pdf` file

Any ideas why it's happens?

This is what I'm currently using to download file (pressing the actually button, to make the process generic)

```
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'plugins':{
        'always_open_pdf_externally': True
    },
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False,
    },
    'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': False,
        'directory_upgrade': True,
        'default_directory': ''
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download that pdf file using `urllib` library

```py
import urllib.request
pdf_url = "https://www.vidahomeloans.co.uk/docs/default-source/product-guide-rate-sheets/residential-rate-sheet.pdf?sfvrsn=27d0a846_16"


def download_file(download_url, filename):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(download_url)
    file = open(filename + ".pdf", 'wb')
    file.write(response.read())
    file.close()


download_file(pdf_url, "Output")
```

Comment: I have updated my question , as to download files I'm physically pressing the button